# Vue3 Expect to show data in console but nothing show

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I am trying to print all documents from a MongoDB collection(collection1Data) on the console, but nothing is appearing. I am unsure what the issue is and I think the position of the console.log statement might be incorrect. the console not show error
console.log(collection1Data.value.filter(data => isRecentlyUpdated(data.updatedAt)));

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
  
    const collection1Data = ref([]);
    const collection2Data = ref([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const [collection1Response, collection2Response] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('https://koh-ontvsound:53500/onboardshows'),
        axios.get('https://koh-ontvsound:53500/onboardlands'),
      ]);
      collection1Data.value = collection1Response.data;
      collection2Data.value = collection2Response.data;
      
      console.log(collection1Data.value.filter(data => isRecentlyUpdated(data.updatedAt)));

    };

    onMounted(() => {
      fetchData();
      setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
    });

    const isRecentlyUpdated = (updatedAt) => {
      const updatedTime = new Date(updatedAt);
      return (Date.now() - updatedTime.getTime()) < 15000;
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't parse the incoming response data

```
collection1Data.value = (await collection1Response.json()).data;
collection2Data.value = (await collection2Response.json()).data;
```

Comment: console show Json is not function Thank you